# Proving or disproving continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with the property that for a fixed vector $a:=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, there exist a finite positive real number $d^{*} \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, such that forall $ d \geq d^{*}$, either $f(a,d) \geq 0$ or $f(a,d) \leq 0$.

An example of such a function would be $f(a,d) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i d^{i-1}$. If we define the function $g(a) = \min \{d^{*}:\forall  d \geq d^{*}$, either $f(a,d) \geq 0$ or $f(a,d) \leq 0\}$. Is this function continuous. If not is the result true for the example function (i.e the polynomial) defined above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Any time you define   $g(a)=\text{last time something happens}$, continuity is going to be lost the moment something stops happening.

Consider the quadratic polynomial $f(x) = (x-1)^2+c$. When $c\ge 0$, it is always nonnegative. When $c<0$, it changes sign as $x$ grows, until it settles at being nonnegative at $x=1+\sqrt{c}$.  So, the smallest $x$ after which there are no sign changes is a discontinuous function of $c$.

You can make this into $f(a,d)=a_1+a_2d+a_3d^3$ with $a_1=1+c$, $a_2=-2$, $a_3=1$.

Comment: Thank you, This example makes it pretty clear.